# In what situations would you use a basis other than the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm in Chapter 3 of Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right".

When finding a matrix for a linear transformation with respect to bases of the domain and codomain, why would we would ever choose to use bases other than the standard bases?
Are there other situations where this is applicable?

Comment: Yes. For example, sometimes one can find a basis where the matrix operator is diagonal. This is really useful in actual calculations.

Comment: The whole theory of Fourier analysis and Fourier series is basically about a change of basis from the standard basis to a different interesting basis. Some linear operators look complicated in one basis but simple in another (simple enough that it is faster for a computer to change basis, apply the simple operator, and change back to the standard basis, than for it to just apply the complicated operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various normal forms, like Jordan or Jordan-Chevalley, and QR (which I've never used), which you can get the matrix into by changing basis.  These forms can make the matrix easier to work with, and prove results.

For instance Jordan normal form consists in upper triangular blocks, with the eigenvalues on the diagonal, and $1$'s on the super diagonal.